# REST API How to separate grant type password and client_credentials in requests?

Tags: api, rest, yii2

I study REST API, please help me to understand one thing. I use in `[this][1]` yii2 library.
For the application, I use the token for requests with `grant_type: client_credentials`, for the user `grant_type: password`.
Let's say I have 5 methods in the rest:

```
GET /users
GET /users/1
PUT /users/1
DELETE /users/1
POST /users/create
```

GET / users should not be accessible to the user, only to the application.

How can I understand in which case I can give an answer, and where should I answer forbidden? Indeed, in both cases, requests will come with an access token. I thought to create 2 applications for each client with different client_id and client_secret (i.e. one will be for the application itself, the second for application users) and use scopes to separate the allowed routes. But I still did not understand how to handle the scope, how to bind them to rbac, how to automatically determine the allowed routes by scope, and yet each user, depending on his state, may have different rights (for example, if an order is canceled, he cannot pay for it and the client does not need to issue this scope). The questions just got bigger.

Tell me what are the best practices for this? And how to do it correctly in this case? If it is not clear, write in the comments - I will correct the question.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I cannot tell you how to implement what you want to achieve as I am not familiar with the yii2 library. Generally speaking, assuming you are conforming to the OAuth2 protocol, scopes is the right way to go to define different access rights for different clients. Additionally, you can use user roles to have different kinds of access rights for individual users.

Comment: For example the client has a "Users_read" scope. The client makes a request for the address "/users". How do I know if the "users_read" scope matches the "/users" address ?

Comment: see at the bottom section "Check access" - https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-controllers Im'not sure you search fo this